# Consumir WebService NFe GO C# Erro 495 Unknown Code

Tags: c#, web-service, nfe, wcf

Estou obtendo o seguinte erro ao tentar consumir o WebService de NFe GO

Erro 90 - NfeStatusServico.
O servidor remoto retornou uma resposta inesperada: (495) Unknown Code

como estou criando uma dll não tenho o arquivo de configuração

```
private System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding getBinding  
    {
        get
        {
            System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpsTransportBindingElement objHttpsTransportBindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.ManualAddressing = false;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.AllowCookies = false;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.BypassProxyOnLocal = false;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.KeepAliveEnabled = true;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.MaxBufferSize = 65536;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.Realm = string.Empty;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.AuthenticationScheme = System.Net.AuthenticationSchemes.Digest;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.UnsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication = false;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.UseDefaultWebProxy = true;
            objHttpsTransportBindingElement.RequireClientCertificate = true;

            TextMessageEncodingBindingElement objTextMessageEncodingBindingElement = new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement();
            objTextMessageEncodingBindingElement.MessageVersion = MessageVersion.Soap12;
            objTextMessageEncodingBindingElement.WriteEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            objTextMessageEncodingBindingElement.MaxReadPoolSize = 64;
            objTextMessageEncodingBindingElement.MaxWritePoolSize = 16;

            System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding objCustomBinding = new System.ServiceModel.Channels.CustomBinding(objTextMessageEncodingBindingElement, objHttpsTransportBindingElement);
            return objCustomBinding;
        }
    }

public void NfeStatusServico(string cUF, string tpAmb, string noSerieCert, string hostWS, string pUF, bool trace)
    {
            Certificado cert = new Certificado();
            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
            System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress address = new System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(hostWS);

            NFeStatusServico4.NFeStatusServico4ServiceClient cliente = new NFeStatusServico4.NFeStatusServico4ServiceClient(getBindingGO, address);
            cliente.Endpoint.Address = address;
            cliente.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.DefaultCertificate = cert.BuscaNroSerie(noSerieCert, false);
            cliente.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = cert.BuscaNroSerie(noSerieCert, false);
string corpoMsg = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
                    "<consStatServ xmlns=\"http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe\" versao=\"" + Le_Config("NFE", "verProc").ToString() + "\">" +
                    "<tpAmb>" + tpAmb + "</tpAmb>" +
                    "<cUF>" + cUF + "</cUF>" +
                    "<xServ>STATUS</xServ>" +
                    "</consStatServ>";


            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.LoadXml(corpoMsg);

            if (trace)
                MessageBox.Show(xmlDoc.DocumentElement.InnerXml, "Envio de Msg - NfeStatusServico4");

            XmlNode retNode = cliente.nfeStatusServicoNF(xmlDoc.DocumentElement);
}
```

Esse metodo esta funcionando para os outros Estados so não para o CE e GO

o que tenho que fazer para ele funcionar para CE e GO

Obrigado

Comment: Por favor alguem me ajuda

Comment: Consegui resolver ajustando na propriedade do projeto -> Aplicativo -> Estrutura de destino = .Net Framework 4.5

Comment: e tambem adicione e alterei ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls; para System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12; funcionou para todos os estados